# Customizing the Android action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I'm trying to customize the action bar of my app, but I can't do it correctly and I don't know why.

I have defined my themes.xml like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name = "ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The AndroidManifest.xml where we call the style is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="coursera.momaproject" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Supposedly, we have to see the action bar background in purple color, but what we have is an action bar with her background in black

[image]

What happened? What am I doing wrong?

---

If I remove android:theme="@style/AppTheme" from my AndroidManifest.xml and I add `getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_alert)));`
on onCreate() method I've got the next error:

```
02-10 12:50:56.458    2512-2512/coursera.momaproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{coursera.momaproject/coursera.momaproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at coursera.momaproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

If I restore my AndroidManifest.xml and remove the actionBar customization, my app gives me an error when I run it.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="coursera.momaproject" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>
</resources>
```

I've got this error:

```
02-10 13:42:33.955    2574-2574/coursera.momaproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{coursera.momaproject/coursera.momaproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at coursera.momaproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

onCreate() method, with ** line where it produces the error ...

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        **getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_alert)));**

        //We add the footer view
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        View seekBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
        container.addView(seekBarView);

        topLeft = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topLeft);
        bottomLeft = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottomLeft);
        topRight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topRight);
        bottomRight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottomRight);

        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                Integer newColor = progressColor(progress, ORIGIN_TOP_LEFT_COLOR, TARGET_TOP_LEFT_COLOR);
                topLeft.setBackgroundColor(newColor.intValue());

                newColor = progressColor(progress, ORIGIN_BOTTOM_LEFT_COLOR, TARGET_BOTTOM_LEFT_COLOR);
                bottomLeft.setBackgroundColor(newColor.intValue());

                newColor = progressColor(progress, ORIGIN_TOP_RIGHT_COLOR, TARGET_TOP_RIGHT_COLOR);
                topRight.setBackgroundColor(newColor.intValue());

                newColor = progressColor(progress, ORIGIN_BOTTOM_RIGHT_COLOR, TARGET_BOTTOM_RIGHT_COLOR);
                bottomRight.setBackgroundColor(newColor.intValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                //We don't do anything

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                //We don't do anything
            }
        });

    }
```

---

My file structure is ...

[image]

Comment: what is `@drawable/ab_solid_example`?

Comment: it's an image wich contains the purple color. I have prove it with @color/purple_color and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Not sure but it could be because of you have different **parent themes** for `AppTheme` and `ActionBar.Solid.Example` try changing parent theme of Actionbar.Solid.Example to `Widget.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: If I try to change the parent theme of ActionBar.Solid.Example to Widget.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar it doesn't work because give me that this parent theme is no correct :(

Comment: okay keep both appTheme and Actionbar.Solid.Example themes same. Either  Holo or AppCompat

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't work :(((

Comment: whats your minSdk and targetSdk version of project?

Comment: Ups!! I haven't defined a minSDK and targetSDK ...

Comment: I have defined minSDK and targetSDK and still doesn't work       <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: See my answer, it 100% works for **API >= 11**, and if it doesn't work, you must have made any mistake somewhere else

Comment: Sorry, but I can't change the style of AppTheme to     "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" because I've got the next error when I run the application:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `minSdkVersion` is **11 or higher** then write

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

in your `.class` file's `onCreate()` method.

Now your class should look like,

```
Class MyActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("YourColor"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt's work to me ... I'm frustrated!!!     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));

        return true;
    }

Comment: @JoséCarlos DO NOT out in onCreateOptionsMenu(), see my answer, I have edited and added how to do it.

Comment: @JoséCarlos and remove your `themes.xml` file and `theme="style/apptheme"` from manifest also.

Comment: Thank you for all!!! I have removed theme=@style/AppTheme from my AndroidManifest and I have added getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_alert))); and ... It doesn't works!!! I have edit my original message with the exception that I get.

Comment: you need to add AppCpmpat theme to your manifest's application tag's android:theme attribute. I told you to remove customized theme and you removed all then how does it suppose to work!

Comment: I have restored my AndroidManifest.xml and remove actionBar customization in themes.xml ... and it doesn't work!!! :(((( See my original post

Answer (score 0):

Edit: See comments

---

If you are using Android Studio's default project template, there is also `values-v21/styles.xml` for the material theme. You will need to change that as well to have it show on Lollipop devices / emulator.

If you are looking at the design tab of Android Studio, you may want to set the "Android version to use when rendering layouts" to a version lower than API 21.

[image]

Comment: In my project there is no /values-v21 directory, but I have another values directory named /values-w820p and I copy inside of it the themes.xml file ...but it doesn't work :( I'm working with API 18 from Android.

Comment: You've got my file structure on the original post. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is that you are mixing AppCompat themes with the built-in stuff. If you want to use the AppCompat theme and the support library, follow the instructions "For Android 2.1 or higher" in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html). Alternatively, since you are only supporting API 11+, you can also change the theme to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` *and* change `MainActivity` to extend `android.app.Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: OMG!!! I have changed the heritance of MainActivity from ActionBarActivity to Activity and change the parent style of AppTheme to @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar and ... It works!!!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Finally, thanks to @Maurice Lam, I have the correct solution to my problem.

The solution is:

1. Change the heritance of `MainActivity` from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity`
2. Change the style of AppTheme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`:

   themes.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <style name="AppThem" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
   </resources>
   ```
3. In onCreate() method, rigth now you can define the color of the ActionBar like this:

   ```
   getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_alert)));
   ```